# I have a problem with my Flutter application, when calling the Isar database

Tags: database, flutter, function, dart, flutter-isar

I have a problem with my Flutter application, when calling the Isar database.
I have the data structure in one page, the functions in another, and the instruction in my main.dart page to create two users if they don't exist, but I don't know how to fix the errors in the `adduser`, `edituser`, and `deleteuser` functions.

```
@Collection()
class User {
  Id? id = Isar.autoIncrement;

  @Index(unique: true)
  String? username;

  String? password;

  bool? isAdmin;

  User({
    this.id,
    this.username,
    this.password,
    this.isAdmin,
  });
}
```

the main.dart page contains

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Revisa si el usuario Admin existe
    IsarQueries.getUserByUsername('admin').then((user) {
      if (user == null) {
        // Crea un nuevo usuario Admin
        final admin = User()
          ..username = 'admin'
          ..password = '1234'
          ..isAdmin = true;
        IsarQueries.addUser(admin);
      }
    });

    // Revisa si el usuario mms existe
    IsarQueries.getUserByUsername('mms').then((user) {
      if (user == null) {
        // Crea un nuevo usuario mms
        final mms = User()
          ..username = 'mms'
          ..password = '4321'
          ..isAdmin = true;
        IsarQueries.addUser(mms);
      }
    });

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Fitgate App'),
      ),
      body: LoginPage(),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    );
  }
}
```

in the page functions I have:

```
  static Future<void> addUser(User user) async {
    await _isar.writeTxn((isar) async {
       isar.user.put(user);
    });
  }

  static Future<void> updateUser(User user) async {
    await _isar.writeTxn((isar) async {
       isar.user.put(user);
    });
  }

  static Future<void> deleteUser(User user) async {
    await _isar.writeTxn((isar) async {
       isar.user.delete(user);
    });
  }
}
```

But these three functions give me the following error

> The argument type 'Future Function(dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future Function()'.

I have watched tutorials and followed a couple of guides, and I have gotten (rid of) a lot of errors, but now I only have these three.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have `"isar"` as a declared variable in the class. If that is true it could be confusing the `isar` in your `writeTxn` function.

If you do change the `isar` to a different one and try again.